# C realloc error

Tags: c, realloc

I am having trouble using realloc to open up memory. I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings that I read in from a file. What I am trying to do is, read the first 200 chars of a line using fgets, if those 200 chars has the new line, I move on to the next line. I have this working nice and dandy. My problem is when the first 200 chars do not have a new line character, I am trying to realloc another 200 chars of space to the string and then concatenate the new two hundred onto the old until it contains a new line. After testing, it appeared that on the second realloc, there is a glibc error of invalid size.

Am I calling realloc wrong? I've read the man page and used that as reference and the book I am using for reference says that since it is sizeof(char) that I don't need to actually include the size of. Could anyone point out where I am going wrong? I greatly appreciate the help.

```
while( (!feof(file)) && lineCount < 11999 ) {               //will loop til end of file
    lines[index] = malloc(201*sizeof(char));                //give 201 spaces for the pointer at index
    fgets(lines[index], 200, file);                         //gets first 200 chars
    temp = strchr(lines[index], '\n');                     //set temp for while loop
       while(temp == NULL){                                //while the string doesnt have \n
           printf("string doesn't have have a newline character\n");
           lines[index]=realloc(lines[index],200);             //lines[index] now has 200 extra space
           printf("added extra space\n");
           fgets(temp2,200,file);                                  //read next 200 chars into temp
           printf("%s",temp2);                                     //for testing print next 200 lines
           temp=strchr(temp2,'\n');                            //for while loop, check if temp has "\n"
           strcat(lines[index],temp2);                              //concat string onto end
           printf("This is lines after cat\n\n\n%s",lines[index]); //testing print


  }//variables are iterated here
}
```

Once again thank you for your time and help.

EDIT: Answered below

Comment: Your `realloc()` calls are making your allocations smaller, not larger.

Comment: what's the point of `realloc()`ating if your size is always `200`? Is it not the case that you want to reallocate to `(previous size) + 200`? Did you **read** the documentation of `realloc()`?

Comment: The size argument to `realloc()` is the _new total size_, not the increment or decrement to the size.

Comment: AHHHH!!! Thank you, the man page has it for a set size increase, not an incremental increase! This makes so much sense!!! Please put your comment as an answer so I can mark as correct!

Comment: Not quite sure here, but do you not also intend to increment `index`? It is perhaps part of *//variables are iterated here*? (As in omitted code ...)

Comment: @ChristopherJordan "the man page has it for a set size increase" – I can hardly believe that. Which man page are you reading, specifically? It's much more likely that you're misinterpreting the man page's phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer.*</sup>

The size argument to `realloc()` is the *new total size*, not the increment or decrement to the size.
Consequently, you are not adding space when you repeatedly call `realloc(lines[index], 200)`.

Also note that the usage:

```
pointer = realloc(pointer, new_size);
```

is dangerous, because if `realloc()` fails, you've lost the pointer to the memory that was allocated before, thereby leaking memory.  Verbose though it is, you should be using:

```
void *new_space = realloc(pointer, new_size);
if (new_space == 0)
    …handle error…
pointer = new_space;
```

---

#### Operational code

Note that I've chosen `INC_SIZE` and `MAX_LINES` to make it easy to test (30 characters is easier than 200; 5 lines is easier than 12,000).  Note also that the code echoes its input immediately upon successfully reading data; this helps debug the code.  It also encloses the string in angle brackets so as to make it easier to know where the ends of the string are.  This can sometimes reveal issues like CRLF (DOS) line endings on a Unix machine, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { INC_SIZE = 30 };
enum { MAX_LINE = 5  };

int main(void)
{
    char *lines[MAX_LINE] = { 0 };
    int lineCount = 0;

    for (lineCount = 0; lineCount < MAX_LINE; lineCount++)
    {
        size_t lineSize = INC_SIZE;
        lines[lineCount] = malloc(lineSize * sizeof(char));
        if (lines[lineCount] == 0)
            break;
        if (fgets(lines[lineCount], INC_SIZE, stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("In-1 <<%s>>\n", lines[lineCount]);
        char *temp = strchr(lines[lineCount], '\n');
        while (temp == NULL)
        {
            printf("string doesn't have have a newline character\n");
            size_t newSize = lineSize + INC_SIZE;
            void *newSpace = realloc(lines[lineCount], newSize);
            if (newSpace == NULL)
                break;
            lines[lineCount] = newSpace;
            lineSize = newSize;
            printf("added extra space\n");
            char temp2[INC_SIZE];
            if (fgets(temp2, INC_SIZE, stdin) == NULL)
                break;
            printf("In-2 <<%s>>\n", temp2);
            temp = strchr(temp2, '\n');
            strcat(lines[lineCount], temp2);
            printf("This is the line after cat: <<%s>>\n", lines[lineCount]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
        printf("Line: <<%s>>\n", lines[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
        free(lines[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you could take a look at my code one more time it would be very helpful. My while loop seems to stop the 200 before the new line. So if it was 1500 chars long, there will only be 1400 in my index. Is there anything you see that can be causing that? My logic seems right that when i set temp inside the while loop it should get everything because it won't cancel until the new line?